# What natural defence mechanism does the human body have against lead poisoning?

Tags: human-evolution, immune-system, adaptation, poison

It is known that lead ion takes place of necessary ions, like calcium, in the body, but does not perform their task, hence wrecking the system. So how does the body eventually recognise this threat and get rid of the lead deposit in the body? And if such a natural defence mechanism exists, why is it not effective enough?

For example, is the process in which lead gets stored in the bones one of the safety mechanism of the body, so that it stays away from other delicate organs?

Comment: INB4 mods put question on hold as too broad I would suggest you to break the question into multiple questions and post them separately.

Comment: @ronisaiba Thanks. I have tried to make the question more specific by removing some sub questions.

Comment: Lead-binding proteins are a common defense in many organisms (https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jt/2011/686050/).